# Why am I receiving this error code, when trying to rename a flash drive?

Tags: macos, finder, error

*Broken image removed*

I receive this error upon attempting to rename a flash drive. The renaming process works, but I would like to know what this error is, and why it's appearing.

Comment: How is the drive formatted? What name are you attempting to assign to it?

Comment: Well, as far as formatting goes, I have no idea. I just took it out of the package and used it. However, the name can be any valid name (no punctuation, correct length, etc.) and the error will still occur.

Comment: I had some ideas, but I haven't been able to replicate your problem yet. What OS version are you running? Does this happen with all flash drives, or just this one?

Comment: This is the only flash drive that I've experienced this error with. Mac OS X 10.7.1.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. No luck so far in replicating your problem, but I'll keep at it.

Comment: Have you tried reformatting the unit to FAT using disk utility and then trying to rename? FAT is the default filesystem for most USB sticks. I had this problem, reformatted it with disk util and it started working.

Comment: @Lyken Never tried, but I will.

Comment: @Lyken That did the trick, you want to make an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried reformatting the unit to FAT using disk utility and then trying to rename? FAT is the default filesystem for most USB sticks. I had this problem, reformatted it with disk util and it started working.